# Is it possible to use php variable as content of twitter bootstrap popover?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I need to use php variable as content of popover. I tried this, but it does not work

`<?php $comment = ORM::factory('mark')->getComment($user_id, $subject, $quarter1[$j][1], $quarter1[$j][0]); ?>
                        <a href="#" id="example" class="btn btn-success" rel="popover" data-content="<?php echo $comment;?>">hover for popover</a>`

Comment: does $comment echo out a value? Or is that the problem?

Comment: $comment returns a string without problems. The problem is that I do not know how to use it in data-content

Answer (score 0):

Add data-toggle="popover" to your anchor. Then try something like this:

```
$("a[data-toggle=popover]")
      .popover({
         html: true,
         animation: true,
         placement: 'bottom',
         trigger: 'manual'
       })
```

In your script file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!

```
<a class="d" rel = 'popover' data-html='true' data-content="<div><?php echo $comment?></div>"  data-original-title='Popover Title' href="#">hover for popover</a>
```